# Atualizar um ComboBox após abrir QDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

Como faço para atualizar um ComboBox após abrir um QDialog?

O código abaixo não atualiza, caso tenha feito uma atualização no db. Tenho que fechar a aplicação e abrir para mostrar os novos dados:

```
Dialog::Dialog(){
  carregar_comboBox();
}

void Dialog::carrega_comboBox(){
    qry..
     while..
     ui->comboBox->addItem(qry.value(0).toString());
}
```

Comment: Você precisa então chamar o `carrega_comboBox()` sempre que mudar algo no DB. Ou usar um model para o compobox.

Comment: @Guilherme Bernal Tem algum modo de chamar o `carregar_comboBox()` quando abrir o `QDialog`? Fica melhor do que ficar vinculando em outras `class`.

Comment: Implemente o sua função `show() { carregar_comboBox(); QDialog::show(); }`.

Comment: Obrigado. consegui funcionar :)

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal dá uma resposta pra gente poder votar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que fica entendido você precisa que a função `carregar_comboBox()` seja chamada sempre antes do dialog ser mostrado na tela. Uma solução simples é re-implementar a função `show()` sobrescrevendo a `QDialog::show()`:

```
class SeuDialog : public QDialog {

    \* ... *\

public:

     // Sempre que alguém chamar essa função para mostrar a dialog...
     void show() {
         carregar_comboBox(); // Primeiro carregue sua ComboBox
         QDialog::show();     // Somente depois mostre de fato a dialog
     }
}
```

Seria interessante também implementar `showMaximized()` de forma similar para que o comportamento seja consistente.